# Angular firebase error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

i keep on getting this error in index.d.ts file for firebase 
**ERROR**

```
Error:(18, 18) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(28, 27) TS1005:',' expected.
Error:(30, 12) TS2314:Generic type 'ErrorFn' requires 2 type argument(s).
Error:(232, 11) TS2314:Generic type 'Observer<T, E, Error>' requires 3 type argument(s).
Error:(239, 11) TS2314:Generic type 'Observer<T, E, Error>' requires 3 type argument(s).
Error:(587, 46) TS2314:Generic type 'Observer<T, E, Error>' requires 3 type argument(s).
Error:(588, 15) TS2314:Generic type 'ErrorFn' requires 2 type argument(s).
Error:(592, 46) TS2314:Generic type 'Observer<T, E, Error>' requires 3 type argument(s).
Error:(593, 15) TS2314:Generic type 'ErrorFn' requires 2 type argument(s).
Error:(701, 24) TS2314:Generic type 'Observer<T, E, Error>' requires 3 type argument(s).
```

**Code**

```
  type ErrorFn<E = Error> = (error: E) => void;
  interface Observer<T, E = Error> 
  error: ErrorFn<E>;
  firebase.Observer<any>
```

can anyone help me with this, i have been stuck for about a week now

Comment: interface Observer<T, E = Error> {
     error: ErrorFn<E>;
 }

Comment: try add block { }

Answer (score 1):

It looks like TypeScript is failing on every type parameter default in the file.  Upgrade to TypeScript 2.3 or newer, which [supports type parameter defaults](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults).

Comment: Thanks, Struggled for 3 days finally this fixed the issue.